# How can I obtain the refresh frequency of my screen?

Tags: opengl, refresh, screen

I'm making a game and I would like to create a vsync. So I need to obtain the refresh time of my screen using C++ (and maybe GLFW library, or using the GL11 library.

Comment: Why not use your driver's VSYNC capability? It'll do a much better job of this. I can understand wanting to cap your framerate, but not actually trying to implement VSYNC by hand, that's really difficult.

Comment: So, how can I enable it?

Comment: It's usually referred to as ***swap interval***. A non-zero value means every n/refresh rate seconds the driver will do a buffer-swap. So, if you set swap interval to 1, then that's 1/60 if your refresh rate is 60 Hz. That works out to 16.66667 ms, and that's how VSYNC works in a nutshell :)

Comment: See [here](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__context.html#ga6d4e0cdf151b5e579bd67f13202994ed) for more details. If your question was really just how to implement VSYNC, I'd be happy to turn this into an actual answer.

Comment: I tried to use this function, but my FPS counter (fraps) tells me 2000 FPS...

Comment: @Seyro97: You probably have VSync disabled hard for all applications in your graphics driver. I'd change that.

Comment: I have a NVIDIA graphic card and it says to me that the application can choose it